# AngularJS How to call directive function from controller

Tags: angularjs

I was looking for a way to find out how to call a function inside a directive from the controller. I got the snip but hence I am new to Angular, the below code flow is not very clear. Anyone mind to explain how the code is working. Thanks.

```
// Directive 
<map set-fn="setDirectiveFn(theDirFn)"></map>

scope: { setFn: '&' },
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.updateMap = function() {
       alert('inside updateMap()');
    }
    scope.setFn({theDirFn: scope.updateMap});
}

// Controller
<button ng-click="directiveFn()">call directive function</button>
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.setDirectiveFn = function(directiveFn) {
        $scope.directiveFn = directiveFn;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Starting with the controller, this block creates a `setDirectiveFn()` method on the `$scope` object in your controller that takes a single parameter (`directiveFn`) and then uses that parameter to create a `directiveFn()` method on the `$scope` object in your controller.

```
    $scope.setDirectiveFn = function(directiveFn) {
        $scope.directiveFn = directiveFn;
    };
```

Inside the directive it is creating an `updateMap()` method on the `scope` object in the directive and then calling the `setFn()` method which is mapped to the `$scope.setDirectiveFn()` method by this line: `<map set-fn="setDirectiveFn(theDirFn)"></map>` in your HTML and this line: `scope: { setFn: '&' }` in your directive. It is passing the `scope.updateMap()` method which effectively sets `$scope.directiveFn()` in your controller equal to `scope.updateMap()` in your directive.

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.updateMap = function() {
       alert('inside updateMap()');
    }
    scope.setFn({theDirFn: scope.updateMap});
}
```

The button is then calling `$scope.directiveFn()` in your controller which has been mapped to `scope.updateMap()` in your directive.

```
<button ng-click="directiveFn()">call directive function</button>
```

Answer (score 11):

you can do it with angular pubsub

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.updateMap = function() {
       alert('inside updateMap()');
    }
    scope.setFn({theDirFn: scope.updateMap});

    scope.$on('eventName', function(event, data){
       //call directive function here
    })
}

function MyCtrl($scope) {

      $scope.$broadcast('eventName', data)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Just call the directive function from your controller/template and initialise that function in your directive using two-way binding symbol**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
 .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){
 })
.directive('tabBar', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        tabClick: '='
    }, 
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabbar.tpl.html',
    link: function(scope) {
                    scope.tabClick = function(str) {
            alert(str);
        }
    }
   };
   });
```

[Working sample](https://jsfiddle.net/e391za4s/)

Note: Tested and working

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading this article : http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-2-isolate-scope

Basically, your directive has an `Isolate Scope` set by `scope: {setFn: '&'}`

What this does is that when you can send data to your directive via attributes, in this case, the `set-fn` attribute.

in your directive, scope.setFn now contains the function sent to it via attribute in your html (`setDirectiveFn(theDirFn)`)

So calling `scope.setFn({theDirFn: scope.updateMap});`

Calls the function defined in

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.setDirectiveFn = function(directiveFn) {
         $scope.directiveFn = directiveFn;
    };
}
```